# JavaScript Filter return on react app delete all object with the same id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to return all object the !== from the object that i deleted now and the filter delete all object with the same name that i clicked.
In my application it is possible to have several identical objects and I want that at the moment of deletion it will be deleted only 1.
here the code

```js
handleClick = packageID => {
    let array = [];
    packageMethods
      .deletePackageFromUser(packageID, this.props.userID)
      .then(res => {
        packageMethods.findPackage(packageID).then(temppackage => {
          array = this.state.package.filter(item => {
            return item._id !== temppackage.data[0]._id;
          });
          this.setState({
            package:array
          })
        });
      });

  };
```

Comment: ```const filteredData = this.state.package.filter((el,_, src) => src.indexOf(el) !== src.indexOf(src.find(item => item.id === temppackage.data[0]._id )))```

Comment: @Bonjov you should study my answer I think you would learn from it. Your solution has much redundancy and has a time complexity of O(n^3), which is very bad.

Comment: Correction: O(n^2) (still bad)

Comment: @Ace are you hater? :))))) i wrote comment and not answer

Comment: @Bonjov nope, just trying to be helpful. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the index of the first instance of an object with that id, then remove the item at that index.

```
handleClick = packageID => {
  let array = [...this.state.package];
  packageMethods
    .deletePackageFromUser(packageID, this.props.userID)
    .then(res => {
      packageMethods.findPackage(packageID).then(temppackage => {
        const removal_index = array.findIndex(item => {
          return item._id === temppackage.data[0]._id;
        });
        array.splice(removal_index, 1);
        this.setState({
          package: array
        })
      });
    });

};
```

Here's an example

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, val: 'a'}, {id: 1, val: 'a'}, {id: 2, val: 'b'}];
console.log(arr);

const removal_index = arr.findIndex(el => el.id == 1); // find index of first object with id of 1
arr.splice(removal_index,1); // remove 1 element starting at `removal_index`
console.log(arr);
```